# How to do unique key constraints for multiple columns in Entity Framework Core 8.0?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, .net-8.0

How to define unique key constraints for multiple columns in Entity Framework Core 8.0 (on .NET 8.0) ?

See the screenshot which I attached - I'm getting an error

> Cannot convert int to string

I tried to fix this problem using string "1" and "2" but using this also throws an error.

Please help how to fix this problem as I have not yet found any solution

[Trying to define unique key constraints for multiple columns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/42yp3.png)

Comment: Are the Primary Key Ids on the associated entities `int` or `string`? If the BankAccount and Staff entities are using integers for their Id/BankAccountId columns then these FKs in this table need to be declared as `int` as well.

Comment: Hmm...Both pk int...So FK  i declare int...but Same error......

Comment: It surely cannot be the exact same error for the same column if there is no conversion between int & string. Check for type mismatches between your entity definition and the table, including any entity configuration.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you are using/trying to use old [`IndexAttribute` from `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.schema.indexattribute?view=entity-framework-6.2.0) which comes with old Entity Framework, not EF Core. If you want (and I recommend you to) use Enitity Framework Core then you should switch to [`Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.IndexAttribute`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.indexattribute.-ctor?view=efcore-8.0#microsoft-entityframeworkcore-indexattribute-ctor(system-string-system-string())) which is valid only on class:

```
[System.AttributeUsage(System.AttributeTargets.Class, AllowMultiple=true)]
public sealed class IndexAttribute : Attribute
```

And accepts names of the index properties - [`IndexAttribute(String, String[])`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.indexattribute.-ctor?view=efcore-8.0#microsoft-entityframeworkcore-indexattribute-ctor(system-string-system-string())):

> **Parameters**
> `propertyName` `String`
> The first (or only) property in the index.
> `additionalPropertyNames` `String[]`
> The additional properties which constitute the index, if any, in order.

```
[Index(nameof(IndexProp1), nameof(IndexProp2), IsUnique = true)]
public class SomeEntity
{
    // ...
}
```

See also:

- [EF Core: Indexes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/indexes?tabs=data-annotations) doc

Answer (score 0):

You can also add a unique constraint through the OnModelCreating method in your DbContext class.

```cs
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<BankAccountUsers>().HasIndex(b => new { b.BankAccountID, b.AssociatedUser }).IsUnique();
}
```